# Reproducing Young's original experiment, modelling the light

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, double-slit-experiment

First of all, this is homework, but me and my partner are trying to reproduce Young's original slitexperiment, with a hole and a card. We've come a bit on the way, we've modelled the light (which actually is monochromatic laser light at the moment, but we are working on the sunlight part). The problem is that our professor is telling us that our model isn't good enough, the light should be depending on a gaussian, which, if I've understood it right, should be depending on a spatial coordinate, let's say $x$ and make the problem one-dimensional.

I cannot seem to understand how the gaussian should look like, I know that it usually is in the form of $\exp(-ax^2)$, but why would it depend on a spatial coordinate in the first place?

Comment: "the light should depend on a gaussian" requires a Lot more information. Does he by chance mean "the intensity cross section of the incident beam should be gaussian"? Or something else? We can't know.

Comment: He means exactly what you said right there, thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: You probably mean two holes in a card.  Note that the holes need to be very small, and very close together.  Try using aluminum foil and a very fine needle, and get the holes so tiny and close together that you can only see them with a magnifying glass.  Gaussian distribution of the light is NOT necessary to demonstrate Young's experiment.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean two holes in a card.  Note that the holes need to be very small, and very close together.  Try using aluminum foil and a very fine needle, and get the holes so tiny and close together that you can only see them with a magnifying glass. If you can't get them close enough together and small enough, you can put a microscope objective downstream from the holes and expand the interference pattern onto a screen. Gaussian distribution of the light is NOT necessary to demonstrate Young's experiment.